# OpenVPN is not listening on any port

Tags: server, 20.04, vpn, openvpn

Dear ladies and gentlemen! I know that there is a lot of questions typical to mine in the Internet, but I could not find the solution anywhere. Maybe someone here can help me?

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 20.04, and there I have installed an OpenVPN server; **it worked for several months** until today all the clients unexpectedly became unable to connect. I deleted and reinstalled/reconfigured VPN, but it does not work though. It should establish TCP connection through the port 1194 (first it was 993, but now I had tried 1194, and both are not working). Moreover, openvpn even does not listen to any of my ports, while it is active.

netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19597           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      988/xe_d000_XE
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      193/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      326/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12098/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      453/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      356/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::1521                 :::*                    LISTEN      794/tnslsnr
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      326/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      453/postgres
```

sudo systemctl status openvpn

```
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2024-02-12 21:23:41 EET; 3h 18min ago
    Process: 306 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 306 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 12 21:23:41 vm-6959-vm454191 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...
Feb 12 21:23:41 vm-6959-vm454191 systemd[1]: Finished OpenVPN service.
```

Here is my server.conf file:

```
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-ipv6 fddd:1194:1194:1194::/64
push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "block-outside-dns"
keepalive 10 120
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
"server.conf" 25L, 467C local ##MY IP
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
```

Can someone graciously help me to understand how to fix the issue, please?

UPDATE:

I have reinstalled openvpn, but it does not listen to any port though. There is the following information in the logs (this message appears every 5 seconds):

```
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 315.
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service for server.
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service for server...
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: OpenVPN 2.4.12 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Aug 21 2023
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, LZO 2.10
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service for server.
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: CRL: loaded 1 CRLs from file crl.pem
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: Note: Cannot set tx queue length on tun0: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Feb 13 20:12:20 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Feb 13 20:12:21 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.1/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
Feb 13 20:12:21 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: /sbin/ip -6 addr add fddd:1194:1194:1194::1/64 dev tun0
Feb 13 20:12:21 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5968]: RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied
Feb 13 20:12:21 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: Linux ip -6 addr add failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Feb 13 20:12:21 vm-6959-vm454191 openvpn[5963]: Exiting due to fatal error
Feb 13 20:12:21 vm-6959-vm454191 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 13 20:12:21 vm-6959-vm454191 systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: `ExecStart=/bin/true` looks like you or something intentionally disabled the service

Comment: So the problem is that I have /bin/true in openvpn.service?


# This service is actually a systemd target,
# but we are using a service since targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

If yes, could you please suggest with what path should I replace it?

Comment: Which executable program file are you trying to run? `ExecStart=/bin/true` literally runs `/bin/true`, which always exit immediately and with an exit code of success. With `Type=oneshot`, that is interpreted as if the service has started successfully

Comment: Dear Daniel, may I ask you what executable file should be indicated in ExecStart field in openvpn.service file to make my Openvpn work?

Comment: Sorry, I posted that from my phone. I found the real problem and I am writing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are targeting the wrong service with your `sudo systemctl status openvpn`. You don't want `openvpn.service` which is a dummy service that just exits immediately with `/bin/true`, and instead want `openvpn-server@server.service`.

According to the [official instructions](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Systemd), you need to create a new instance of the `openvpn-server@.service` template. You named your config `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf` , so the systemd instance name you need to create is `server`:

```bash
# Enable and start the service
sudo systemctl enable --now openvpn-server@server
# Check the status and for any errors
systemctl status openvpn-server@server
journalctl -u openvpn-server@server
```

If furthermore you get [`/sbin/ip -6 addr [...] RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied`](https://bodhilinux.boards.net/thread/450/wireguard-rtnetlink-answers-permission-denied), then let's fix IPv6.

1. Open `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the following to the bottom:

   ```
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
   net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
   ```
2. `sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: Thank you so much, Daniel! I had created the file in /usr/lib/systemd/system directory and rebooted my VPS, but, unfortunately, none port listens to Openvpn as before. May I ask you to suggest a piece of advice, please?

By the way, when I run the command added to the file, I have the following message:

# sudo systemctl enable --now openvpn-server@server

The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Comment: I see that some fields in some config file are missing, but I have no idea what should I add and where is that file. May I humbly ask you for your help?

Comment: You should not create any file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`. The only file you (already) created is `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`. Do not create any systemd files with anything between the `@` and the `.` . The `@` means that it's a systemd template. If `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service` is missing, then you need to `sudo apt install openvpn` , and remove anything you installed using the old method

Comment: I am sorry for my low qualification, but, frankly speaking, I thought that I need openvpn-server@server.service. I have openvpn-server@.service generated by the system, but I did not touch it because it does not have "service" between @ and .

Comment: You do indeed need `openvpn-server@server.service` . It will be created automatically somewhere under `/etc` after you run `sudo systemctl enable --now openvpn-server@server` . But you should not need to touch `/usr/lib` or add a `openvpn-server@server.service` file in that wrong location.

Comment: @Ratherius Don't edit any `.service` files. Just run my `systemctl enable [...]` command

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, I see. When I run the command in question, I have the following error: The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=, Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Comment: Dear Daniel, could you graciously tell me where are these missing fields, and what values should I add?

Comment: I have opened openvpn-server@service, and in the [Install] section I have only WantedBy=multi-user.target.

Comment: When you run that command (I tested on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 VM), you should see `Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvpn-server@server.service → /lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service.`. You may have edited the wrong file. Do `sudo apt purge openvpn` , `find /etc/systemd` and delete all openvpn-related files, then `find /usr`, then delete all openvpn-related files, then reinstall it with `sudo apt install openvpn`

Comment: Thank you so much for your great patience! I did everything you said, I saw the message "Created symlink", but... openvpn still listens on no port :( Can you suggest anything, please?

Comment: Did you reboot or start the service? If you did that, then `journalctl -u openvpn-server@server` will show you the error. Please edit the original question to include it

Comment: Dear Daniel, I have updated the original question, could you please kindly check the new information?

Comment: @Ratherius Have you tried removing the `server-ipv6` line from your `server.conf` file since IPv6 is not set up properly on your machine?

Comment: I have just tried to remove it, but the situation is the same and I have the same logs in journalctl (certainly, I have rebooted the machine).

Comment: Try the IPv6 solution at https://bodhilinux.boards.net/thread/450/wireguard-rtnetlink-answers-permission-denied

Comment: Dear Daniel! Thank you so much for your patient precious assistance. At last it works! :)